# Detox React native reloading with no sense

Tags: react-native, detox, e2e

So I'm getting desperate about this. I'm just trying to setup detox for my react native project and this is my first test using it. When the test starts, it reload like 2-3 times before actually starting the tests, but this does not really bothers me.

Problem comes when executing the first test, it will type in the first input and then the app will reload, apparently for no reason.

Any help here? Here is my code.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code as codeblock and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

remove this from your code

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.releadReactNative();
});
```